# To create an alias for grep and to exclude svn directory

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc, subversion

To create an alias for grep and to exclude svn directory (currently no questions cover this) on bash env I did:

```
$ function gp {grep -rnIi --exclude-dir='.svn';}
```

However,
I get error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Kusalananda showed you how to define a ``gp`` function, but he didn’t explicitly identify the error in your attempt, which is that ``{`` must be followed by a space (or a newline).

Comment: Thanks Scott and Kusalananda. I changed my code to and it works: function gp() { grep -rnIi --exclude-dir='.svn' $1 $2;}

Answer (score 0):

function is not alias

```
alias gp="grep -rnIi --exclude-dir='.svn'"
```

Comment: As a function:  `gp () { grep ... "$@"; }`

Answer (score -1):

I changed my code to:

```
function gp() { grep -rnIi --exclude-dir='.svn' $1 $2;}
```

and it works

Comment: It’s better to use `"$@"`, as Kusalananda suggested. It automatically expands to *all* the arguments that are passed to the function (i.e., ```$1 $2 $3 $4 …```), so you can run it on many files / directories at once, and it quotes them, so your pattern and filenames can have spaces and special characters.